Correct place to store data required for custom addon
When planning for a blender addon, I found I need to download and store some dependencies(not python package, but some binaries, text file etc).
After reading manual and searching google for hours I can't find a solid answer explaining which path should I be using.
Should I be fine just using script's parent directory (one returned from pathlib.Path(__file__).parent which would be user_dir/scripts/addons/) or should be using something else, perhaps ./datafiles/ ?

It would be logical to store the data in the add-on's folder so when the user wants to migrate Blender's preferences they can just copy their preferences folder. If you store it elsewhere it can cause confusion when moving the preferences so that's sort of expected location for everything that your add-on uses. There are of course exceptions - if for example your add-on deals with assets that take significant amount of space, you might want to let them choose. I would say you should not store anything outside the add-on's folder unless you have a very good reason for it. There are no official rules as far as I know. Add-ons can do whatever is needed.

That makes tons of sense! one thing might be that one of file I need is about 8GB in size so it might be troublesome  as you mentioned... but since this will be mere POC/prototype so people can live with that I guess!
